# Does flutter have a live preview of the editing layout?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm just starting to learn flutter and one thing I'm missing now is the layout preview that I had in Android Studio when editing a layout for an Android app. Does flutter have something similar?
What I'm looking for is something that renders the layout I'm editing with placeholder texts inside Android Studio. I know flutter has a good hot-reload, but it's not very good for my specific case. My PC can't handle the android emulator well and I would like to see the result of my changes on my monitor and not having to keep looking down at my phone to see the changes. Based on my searches by now, flutter doesn't have anything like that. Is that correct?

Comment: You could try to run your project as [flutter for web](https://flutter.dev/web) to be able to preview. Apart from that you could try other Android Emulators, but they require more configuration than the seamless integration that the original Android Emulator has with Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there are available non-mobile options that are fitted for learning or at least to run your application preview. These are currently under development.

- [Flutter for desktop](https://flutter.dev/desktop), check [this for samples](https://flutter.dev/desktop#samples-and-codelabs).
- [Flutter for web](https://flutter.dev/web), which is now available in Flutter beta channel.
- Another option is to use [device_preview](https://pub.dev/packages/device_preview). This allows you to leverage Flutter desktop support to see how your app will look on mobile form-factors.

Comment: wow, thanks for the Device Preview package !

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. There is no other way to preview the layout without the hot-reload. If the emulators are too heavy for your PC, you can run your project on your navigator while scaling it to a mobile phone size.
Keep in mind that some plugins aren't compatible for web.